# Ubuntu server12.04 not connecting to other LAN (via site-to-site VPN)

Tags: 12.04, server, 64-bit

dear community members:

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 server (x64), and planned using it as a web server within a local network, which has 3 physical locations connected via site-to-site VPN.  I have found the NIC card is set up correctly by looking through `ifconfig`, and able to `ping google.com` with no issue so the nameserver is also fine.

**Problem is**: I can only connect to the servere via workstations within the same LAN (`192.168.12.x`), any computers from other 2 LANs (`192.168.11.x` and `192.168.16.x`) can not connect with the server.  It initially connected for a little while, but then all of sudden stopped.  I tried to stop fire wall (`ufw`) and put all AppArmor profiles in complain mode. Still not helping. please help me to direct what to do?  thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The *ping* to google is using the default routing and does only show that your internet connection seems to work ;-)

For other local LAN networks you have two possibilities.

#### different *logical* LAN on the same physical hardware

If you use different *logical* LAN on the same physical hardware (e.g. for security reasons), you have to ensure that the used *netmask* on the interface covers all used LAN addresses.

#### routing between really different LAN

For this you should know which server is connected to the other (e.g. 192.186.11.*) network **and** your network.

For this purpose you can use the `ip` (or the old fashioned `route`) command.
For a permanent solution you have to tweak ether your dhcp server or local network configuration (`/etc/network/interfaces`).